# Is laravel php stripe module has redirect url after success or failed

Tags: laravel, asynchronous, payment, laravel-cashier

**Does Laravel support the stripe `charge` method async checkout?**

I am using the laravel stripe module, I receive payment with the `charge` method, but there is a possibility of a timeout. If the `charge` method is successful if the successful URL fails, is there a failed URL?

```php
$user->charge(200,$paymentMethodId);
```

I want to make the `charge` async, is there a way?

If the successful, the issue is redirect  to `foo/successful`, otherwise `foo/failed`

Answer (score 0):

The stripe API document says it should return an error if anything wrong happens in the proccess. So you can check what is returned from the Stripe API.

```
try {
  $user->charge(200,$paymentMethodId);
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
  echo 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '\n';
  echo 'Type is:' . $e->getError()->type . '\n';
  echo 'Code is:' . $e->getError()->code . '\n';
  // param is '' in this case
  echo 'Param is:' . $e->getError()->param . '\n';
  echo 'Message is:' . $e->getError()->message . '\n';
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

Comment: Thanks (Teşekürler Gökhan) .ı  found answer  of this question 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types

Comment: You're welcome. Rica ederim :) tahimn ettim de yine de yazmak istedim.